# Where do I get arpa/inet.h?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, sockets

Question is really simple.
I need a tool to convert `char*` to ip adress and use it in

```
sockaddr_in.s_addr
```

arpa/inet.h has `inet_addr()` function, but I am not sure if I already have this file somewhere in MS VS 2010 installation or should I get it elsewhere.

Comment: Check with Al Gore, as he invented the internet.

Comment: @Bogatyr Really? I got one of copies from 
http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/manpages/headers/arpa/inet.html and some dummy files from redistributable files in apps on my PC and this description also - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_addr.html Correct answer is to avoid using it on Windows, do I need Al Gore for this?

Comment: Yeah, you'd probably be using some AlGorithms and guess who invented them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Win32 provides its own implementation of the sockets API (Winsock) which uses slightly different headers.

From the [MSDN for `inet_addr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Header Winsock2.h

Comment: Thanks, that's makes everything better.

Answer (score 15):

`arpa/inet.h` is the include used on Unix-like systems.

On Windows, you must use `winsock2.h`.

[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the MSDN.