# Cannot open include file: 'arpa/inet.h':

Tags: c, visual-c++-2012

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

I am getting this type of error

> Cannot open include file: 'arpa/inet.h':

How do I include this header file? I am actually doing this code in VC++2012.

Comment: Why do you want to include this file?

Comment: definitions for internet operations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do I get arpa/inet.h?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543940/where-do-i-get-arpa-inet-h)

Answer (score 17):

Windows uses different headers and implementation for Berkeley sockets instead of the Unix `<arpa/inet.h>` headers; you need to use a different header and group of functions.

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
```

More information about this is in the [Winsock2 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673(v=vs.85).aspx).

See also: [Where do I get arpa/inet.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20544031/2441252).